# C# string manipulation

Tags: c#, string

I have a string like
A150[ff;1];A160;A100;D10;B10'

in which I want to extract A150, D10, B10

In between these valid string, i can have any characters. The one part that is consistent is the semicolumn between each legitimate strings.

Again the junk character that I am trying to remove itself can contain the semi column

Comment: I think you may need to define more precisely what you mean by "junk character". From your example, I'm not even sure what rules you are using to determine what you want to extract.

Comment: why don't you extract A160 or A100? I agree with @Greg - more information about the rules of extraction are needed

Comment: actually, I am using a project management tool in which I get a string like 
A150[ff+1];A160;A150[ff-1]
where ff strands for first to finish and +1 meaning lead, -1 meaning lag.

i ll always get the characters taht I want to remove between the brackets. 

Sometimes, I may not get any characters. IN that case, the string will be simply A150;A160.

Answer (score 3):

Without having more detail for the specific rules, it looks like you want to use [String.Split](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b873y76a.aspx)(';') and then construct a regex to parse out the string you really need foreach string in your newly created collection. Since you said that the semi colon can appear in the "junk" it's irrelevant since it won't match your regex.

Answer (score 1):

```
        var input = "A150[ff+1];A160;A150[ff-1]";
        var temp = new List<string>();
        foreach (var s in input.Split(';'))
        {
            temp.Add(Regex.Replace(s, "(A[0-9]*)\\[*.*", "$1"));
        }
        foreach (var s1 in temp.Distinct())
        {
            Console.WriteLine(s1);   
        }
```

produces the output

```
A150
A160
```

Answer (score 0):

First,you should use 
string s="A150[ff;1];A160;A100;D10;B1";
s.IndexOf("A160");
Through this command you can get the index of A160 and other words.
And then s.Remove(index,count).

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to remove the 'junk' inbetween the '[' and ']' characters you can use regex for that

```
   Regex regex = new Regex(@"\[([^\}]+)\]");

   string result = regex.Replace("A150[ff;1];A160;A100;D10;B10", "");
```

Then String.Split to get the individual items